# Eigenvalues of a complex matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix

$$
R_x(\alpha) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) & -i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
-i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The characteristic polynomial is

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \lambda\right)^2 + \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) &= \cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - 2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \lambda^2 + \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
&= \lambda^2 -2\lambda\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + 1,
\end{align},
$$

and has roots $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$, hence these are the eigenvalues.
However, we have

$$
\begin{align}
R_x(\alpha)\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) & -i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
-i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
-i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right)\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$

Thus $\left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right)$ is also an eigenvalue.
But this is not possible, because $R_x(\alpha)$ is an operator on a $2$-dimensional vector space and so it cannot have 3 distinct eigenvalues.

I can't find where I made a mistake.

Comment: Remark: it is a combination of Pauli matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \lambda\right)^2 + \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) &= \cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - 2\color{red}{\lambda}\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \lambda^2 +\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
&= \lambda^2 -2\color{red}{\lambda}\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + 1,
\end{align},
$$

The product of the roots should gives me $1$, but the products of  $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$ give me $\cos(\alpha)$.

The correct eigenvalues are $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \color{red}{i}\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) -  \color{red}{i}\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to place a lambda there. Could you be more specific in how you found those eigenvalues?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the mistake. I considered $4\cos^2(\frac{\alpha}{2}) - 4 = 4\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})$. Thanks.